# Adjusting size in geom_text for geom_bar standard positioning

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am able to effectively change the size of labels for bar graphs following the position = dodge format. However, when attempting to do the same with simply stat = identity, I receive a little legend on the side specifying the size, and the size of the labels themselves do not appear to change.

Most questions on SO are the opposite of this, having trouble changing sizes when only using position dodge. I have not seen a similar problem to this in my searches.

```
library(ggplot2)
names <- c("Yes", "No")
values <- c(100, 80)
prac <- data.frame(names, values)

ggplot(data = prac, aes(x = names, y = values, label = values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(size = 50))
```

[image]

It appears that the size does not change.

```
ggplot(data = prac, aes(x = names, y = values, label = values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(size = 5))
```

[image]

However, using position = dodge, the problem does not exist. The sizes change as they're supposed to.

```
names2 <- c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")
values2 <- c(100, 80, 110, 70)
area <- c("Large", "Small", "Small", "Large")
prac2 <- data.frame(names2, values2, area)

ggplot(data = prac2, aes(x = names2, y = values2, label = values2, fill = area)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), size = 5)
```

[image]

Lastly, it should be noted that whether or not the label is specified in the ggplot line or the geom_text line, the same output is produced.

```
ggplot(data = prac, aes(x = names, y = values)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = values, size = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: move size outside of `aes()`

Comment: like you did in the dodge example code

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't figure out what was wrong and I've been dealing with this for a while. Finally had to ask. Kind of disappointing it was so simple